# How to run a RegisterStartupScript in update panel on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager, registerstartupscript

Hi I'm try to get the RegisterStartupScript to appear after I handle the exception. But when i handle the exception it updates the whole page instead of a portion of a page.

Is there some way that I could get it to update only a portion of the page.

I know you can use update panel to achieve this but I could only get it to work on button click, is there some way to make it work on page load?

Code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Login Again');window.location ='Login.aspx';", true);
```

Comment: Consider using ScriptManager.RegisterScriptBlock for your purpose. Use the updatepanel as the first argument to this function.

Answer (score 2):

The whole page is reloading as from what I can see in your example you are instructing the browser to request the Login page again (instead of performing a postback to the current page).

If you need to redirect to this page you could include a value in the query string or session etc.. that you can then check on the Page_Load method (this would still reload the whole page though).